# Everyone's : everyone is conjunction

Tags: word-choice, grammar

Is "Everyone's a loser" a grammatically correct sentence? Can you use "everyone's" as "everyone is" instead of just a possessive term?

Comment: Conjunction? Do you mean contraction? If so, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, correct. *Everyone's* in **Everyone's a loser** is a contraction of *Everyone is*.

Comment: So how do you tell the difference between the contraction (everyone is) and the possessive (belonging to everyone)?  It it just ambiguous?